# How to set data values as labels in Chart.js with a Radar Chart

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I'm trying use set data as the labels in my Radar Chart and I seem to be struggling with this. I have tried reading the documentation and searching online, but not able to find a solution.

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve:
https://photoland.io/i/2LXlet

It would be a huge help if someone could point me in the right direction to get this done.

Thank you

Comment: Have you taken a look at: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html

Comment: There is no option to do this with radar charts, The only relevant config I found is the pointLabels setting, but there is no default settings to do what I'm trying to do. I don't know if its possible to do this with custom callback functions.

Comment: I will take a look

Comment: Would you mind sharing a jsfiddle or a code pen with an example so I can mess with it? I saw the documentation on the radar chart and I don't think it should be that hard. I had to do something similar, but with a different library

Answer (score 0):

I created a code pen for this, hopefully this solves your issue. You can do a whole bunch of different things like create an `object` and use individual `properties` as different labels, create an `array` and select individual values. Whatever you want really.

https://codepen.io/gabedesigns/pen/rqgPPR

Good luck